# mongo couldn't connect to server

Tags: mongodb

Even after reinstalling mongo, I face the same problem on my Mac machine. On a fresh reinstall, I keep getting this error, when typing `mongo` on my Mac terminal.

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:372:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

How can I get this problem fixed? Please help.
Also using, `mongod` on the terminal is throwing this error

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.697+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.697+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.701+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.701+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"thread1","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"thread1","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":8085,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Amijeets-MacBook-Pro.local"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"5.0.6","gitVersion":"212a8dbb47f07427dae194a9c75baec1d81d9259","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.4.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.702+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.704+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23024,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Failed to unlink socket file","attr":{"path":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock","error":"Permission denied"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.704+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23091,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Fatal assertion","attr":{"msgid":40486,"file":"src/mongo/transport/transport_layer_asio.cpp","line":989}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-04-08T16:34:40.704+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"-",        "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}
```

How do I get this fixed? please help!
I thank you already :)

Comment: According to the logs, you just have to remove manually the `/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock` file.

Comment: Hey, I didn't find any file named "mongodb-27017.sock" in /tmp. How can I get this to work?